# Gson doesn't parse enum field in custom class

Tags: java, android, json, gson

My model classes:

```
 public class Model {
        .......
        public ArrayList<Job> Jobs; 
    }

    public class Job {
        public ActionType Action;
        ........

        public enum ActionType {
            NONE(0),
            .......
            GOTO(9);

            private int number;

            private ActionType(int number) {
                this.number = number;
            }

            public int getNumber() {
                return this.number;
            }

             public static ActionType fromKey(int number) {
                  for(ActionType type : ActionType.values()) {
                       if(type.getNumber() == number) {
                            return type;
                       }
                  }
                  return null;
             }
        }
    }
```

Custom deserializer:

```
public class ActionTypeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ActionType> {
    @Override
    public ActionType deserialize(JsonElement element, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        int key = element.getAsInt();
        return ActionType.fromKey(key);
    }
}
```

And here I parse the JSON document:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(ActionType.class, new ActionTypeDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

result = gson.fromJson(valuesArray, new TypeToken<Collection<Model>>(){}.getType());
```

And example of "Jobs" array:

```
[
     {
        "Id":1,

        "Jobs":[
           {
              "Action":1,
              "ItemDescription":""
           },
           {
              "Action":2,
              "ItemDescription":"Item C"
           }
        ]
     }
]
```

**The problem** is that Action is always null in Job class instance.

Comment: What version of Gson are you using? I'm unable to reproduce your issue using your own code on the current 2.2.4 version of Gson. The JSON `[{"Jobs":[{"Action":0}]}]` correctly deserializes to a `Collection<Model>` with the proper enum set in the `Job` object. It may be worth posting a sample of your actual JSON as perhaps there's an issue there.

Comment: @BrianRoach I've updated JSON sample. There you can seen an array of Model objects.

Comment: Works perfectly on my machine using Gson 2.2.4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the JSON is the one you are actually using - action could be null if you fail to correctly match the ID with the enum e.g. id=10 but you don't have an enum for that value.

Your de-serializer should not return NULL but throw an exception.

```
public class ActionTypeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ActionType> {
    @Override
    public ActionType deserialize(JsonElement element, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        int key = element.getAsInt();
        final ActionType actionType = ActionType.fromKey(key);
        if(actionType == null)
            throw new JsonParseException("Can't parse actiontype for key " + key);
        return actionType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternately, if there's an appropriate default (`NONE` in this case?) you could return that instead of null.